# Проблема с роутингом Yii2

Tags: yii2, роутинг

У меня есть такая конфигурация

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => require(__DIR__ . '/urls.php'),
    ]
```

если заходит на главную - он все хорошо обрабатывает. но если на любую другую страницу вида

```
http://site.ru/register или http://site.ru/main
```

говорит ***Not Found*** [скрин](https://yadi.sk/i/6veLi5ILvKpQ8)

в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите что у вас в файле `urls.php`

Comment: файл urls.php - https://yadi.sk/d/Wn2_igNsvLfua

Comment: Вы добавили .htaccess  в проект?

Comment: нет. можете подсказать как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте рядом с `index.php`, в папке `web`, файл `.htaccess`, и напишите в нем:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, помогло